# Why 500 error is not catched in try block?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8 / livewire App I make component for user registration
and when I have 500 error, the error is not catched in try block, as I expected, but I got common laravel
modal dialog with error description. In my app/Http/Livewire/Register.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Sentinel;
use App\Models\User;
use DB;

class Register extends Component
{
    public $form
        = [
            'name'           => 'newuser',
            'email'       => 'newuser@site.com',
            'password'            => '111111',
            'password_2'            => '111111',
            'first_name'         => 'Fname',
            'last_name'         => 'Lname',
        ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.register')
            ->layout('layouts.frontpage');
    }


    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate(User::getUserRegisterValidationRulesArray(null), User::getValidationMessagesArray());

        \Log::info('-2 store $this->form ::' . print_r($this->form, true));

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $newUser = Sentinel::registerAndActivate([
                'username' => $this->form['name'],  // in db I have name field, so that raise runtimeerror!
                'email'    => $this->form['email'],
                'password' => $this->form['password']
            ]);

            DB::commit();
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('FrontendPageMessageSuccess', [
                'title'     => 'Registration',
                'message'   => 'You were successfully registered !'
            ]);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack(); // THIS BLOCK IS NOT RUN!
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('FrontendPageMessageWarning', [
                'title'     => 'Registration',
                'message'   => 'Registration error : ' . $e->getMessage()
            ]);

        }       
    } // public function store()
```

printscreen :
https://prnt.sc/1umpnzb

How can it be fixed ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the error you see in your error block?

Comment: I added printscreen in my question

Comment: just change `username` to `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error said

> Field `name` doesn't have a default value

that's happen because you pass `username` instead of `name` so you need to fix it like this

```
$newUser = Sentinel::registerAndActivate([
  'name' => $this->form['name'],
  'email'    => $this->form['email'],
  'password' => $this->form['password']
]);
```

if you want to catch this error you need to edit the `catch` block and change the `Exception` to `QueryException` instead

```php
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;

try {
   //
} catch(QueryException $e) {
  //
}
```